# Django objects.filter with list and 5 instances from each match

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I have a scenario where I have a Property model which has an attribute of rating. The Property model has thousands of properties with different ratings. I need to retrieve properties from db based on the following criteria,

1) If I have a rating_list = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3, unrated] I know I can easily achieve it by doing

```
Property.objects.filter(rating__in=rating_list)[:50]
```

The issue is that since I have thousands of properties of different ratings there is a chance that the above query returns 50 properties of only 5 ratings, while I need 10 properties for each rating in the filter.

2) Another requirement is I want the returned results to be exactly in the same order as given in the rating_list. 
For e.g, the queryset should contain the first 10 properties of rating 5 and next 10 for rating 4 and next rating 1 so on and so forth.

3) Since we have thousands of properties we want to do it in a single query not in more than a single query.

Is there any solution to achieve this or what could be a possible solution.

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Only a single model of Property which has an attribute of rating and I want filter using that rating attribute. the criteria for the filters are mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a union of the querysets, and limit that union, for example:

```
Property.objects.filter(rating=5)[:10].union(
    Property.objects.filter(rating=4)[:10],
    Property.objects.filter(rating=1)[:10],
    Property.objects.filter(rating=2)[:10],
    Property.objects.filter(rating=3)[:10],
    Property.objects.filter(rating=unrated)[:10],
    all=True
)
```

By using `union`, the order is normally respected.

The `.union` is performed in a single query, the SQL will look like:

```
          (SELECT * FROM appname_property WHERE rating=5 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM appname_property WHERE rating=4 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM appname_property WHERE rating=1 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM appname_property WHERE rating=2 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM appname_property WHERE rating=3 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM appname_property WHERE rating=unrated LIMIT 10)
```

Since filtering can be expensive, you might want to add a [**`db_index=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on the `rating` filed:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked for me but one thing if you look on the third criteria I need to retrieve the list in the same order as my rating_list which is not an ASC or DESC order. Is that possible for we could do it in the same query?

Comment: @UsmanHussain: we retrieve it in the same order, note the order of the `rating=` filters, first we filter on `5`, the `4`, then `1`, etc. (the initial answer was DESC since somehow I had the idea that you were looking for that).

Comment: Any idea on calling .values_list("rating") at the end is returning me queryset of object ids instead of the rating values? :(

Comment: @UsmanHussain: why do you use `.values_list` in the first place? Normally it is not a good idea to fetch scalar values, `.values_list`, etc are often only effective in `GROUP BY` clauses, etc.

Comment: @UsmanHussain: the reason that will not work is that after the slicing,  most clauses are no longer applicable.

Comment: Actually you are right it's not a good idea, I am doing it because I have one Foreignkey attribute on Property model named as `giata` so I am doing it like this,
.values_list("id", "giata_id__provider_ref")

Comment: @UsmanHussain: what if you use `Property.objects.filter(rating=5).values_list("id", "giata_id__provider_ref")[:10].union(...)` (so each time `.values_list` *before* the slicing)?

Comment: I have no issue what would you suggest for a better and optimized approach, the one you suggested above or if I use list comprehension like below after the execution of the query but it will do another query on foreign key model 
`[(property.id, property.giata.provider_ref) for property in properties]`
Which would be a better and optimized solution?

Comment: @UsmanHussain: if performance is an issue, then indeed using `.values_list` will be better, since then you limit the amount of data from the database to the Python/Django level.

Comment: Thanks for giving this much support/help with the explanation.